# Should most feature-requests be discussions first?

Tags: best-practices, discussion

I'm thinking about a Best Practices approach to suggesting feature requests. Perhaps they should always be general brainstorming discussions and re-tagged to feature request only when they get enough momentum.

As a recommend procedure this might cut down the amount of requests only one person wants for those that could be restrained by a community consensus.

Answer (score 5):

I think a feature request includes an implicit request for discussion.  Each request has pros and cons that need to be dealt with, and sometimes the problem that leads to the request could be solved in a better, simpler, more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the benefit of this. I don't think there's so much traffic in Meta that it's hard to separate the wheat from the chaff.

If someone is requesting a feature, it's a feature request. Yes, that request should generate discussion in the answers, but I'm sure Jeff is capable of spotting a feature request that doesn't get much support.